# Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I completely new to Android Development and can't seem to resolve this error: 
*"Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback"*

This is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha01"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha01"


androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I've googled some and ended up on the developer page about "Resolve duplicate class errors", but I'm still not able to fix this. Help would be very much appriciated!

Comment: @toobsco42, `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'` and `implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1'` might duplicate some APIs. What happens if you comment out one of those?

Comment: I don't have the same dependencies that Michael_Oslo has. Also I don't have androidx dependencies. I'm just getting the same error  `Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback`

Comment: what happens if you remove "implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1'" or downgrade.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Option 1**

Following worked for me
Add the following in your gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = false
```

**Option 2** (if above does't work)

1. `Android studio` -> `Navigate` -> `Class`
2. Check include non-project classes
3. Copy full class path android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
4. See where it is used. You may need to remove, one of them.

**Option 3**
you might be including package which is including modules as well so exclude the support-v4 module with following method

```
implementation ('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
}
```

You can analyze the conflicting modules using `./gradlew :YOURPROJECT:dependencies` from a command line in your project repository.
Check especially your third party libraries for occurences of "com.android.support-":

### [image: terminal_output]

Then exclude the conflicting modules from these dependencies like:

```
   implementation ("com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotation'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'
}
```

Comment: Option 1 was the one for me! How would one come to this conclusion? To add this to gradle.properties is fine, but I followed a guide on the developer.google-site and I said nothing about this.

Comment: In my case option 1 worked but with: android.enableJetifier=true. And then I had to invalidate caches / restart

Comment: I tried Option 1 and Option 3 (exclude dependency `dagger-android-support`) but after it show error: `Could not find method com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16() for arguments [build_52wgz5jkz60yl2yx90c3wcy3t$_run_closure2$_closure6@68a7e350] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

Answer (score 27):

Im using `flutter`, and Im adding some native libraries in android, I tried the solutions posted here, but the trick for me was `android.enableJetifier = true` instead false

So, adding the following code to the `gradle.properties`, my apps are running:

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = true
```

Comment: Also see [D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54773290/432903)

Comment: This works for me and after I get another error about **dex enabled**, you can see here [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20747#issuecomment-414126225)

Answer (score 3):

if you still getting error after

```
# gradle.properties
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = false
```

then you probably forgot about main activity that calling **android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity**
change it to **androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

adding following plugins

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter

solved the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

At least for me the issue was with the `implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1'` dependency.  I went into the menu in Android Studio to create a Blank Fragment in Kotlin just to see what that would look like and the dependency above was added.

Once i removed that dependency the error went away.

Comment: Another thing that worked for me was Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX option in Android Studio.  This seemed to resolve any things I may have missed when trying to do the AndroidX migration one dependency at a time.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

Some of your existing dependencies are using older versions of support library, try this

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1' {  
exclude group: 'com.android.support'  
exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```