# Migrate to AndroidX - "Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, androidx

I am in the middle of migrating to androidX and blocked by this exception.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: 
android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback$StubApi21",
"sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

This is how my app's dependencies looks like,

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.adobe.mobile:adobeMobileLibrary:4.17.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:${retrofitLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${okHttpLibraryVersion}"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:${bouncyCastleVersion}"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0"
    implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.7'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.5'
    testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:${okHttpLibraryVersion}"
    testImplementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11'
    testImplementation 'pl.pragmatists:JUnitParams:1.1.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'

    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test:runner:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test:rules:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    })
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:${okHttpLibraryVersion}"

}
```

I already tried to exclude this module like below,

```
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat'
```

Really not sure about this, as excluding like this, may break the features during runtime.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you exclude `com.android.support` from `androidx` ...does that make sense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CustomActionCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389533/program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-media-mediabrowsercompatcustom)

Comment: just update `com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1` to a version which uses `androidx`.

Comment: you are absolutely right!, I just provided a broad answer for this

Answer (score 0):

1). The first step should be, get the dependency graph/tree using,

```
gradlew app:dependencies --scan
```

(app is the module name in my case)

2). then figure out, which one is using the affected module, in my case, it is **support-compat** & **support-media-compat** in **firebase-core** dependency

Excluding the affected module, helps me to compile, but it is crashing as the excluded module is used at the run time, so that’s not the right thing.

3). The trick here is, update all the dependencies to the latest version.

Once you migrated to the **AndroidX**, if you are getting compilation error, make a note of it, just commenting out those lines, actually helps you to compile but that’s not the right way. You need to see whether the affected dependency is migrated to **AndroidX** or still using support libraries instead.

**You can't do much if the affected dependency is not yet migrated to AndroidX.**, if the dependency is generating code that uses support libraries

Comment: *You can't do much if the affected dependency is not yet migrated to AndroidX.* this is only true if the dependency is generating code that uses support libraries. Jetifier handles everything else

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding this line into `Gradle`. [Google Document](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/media)

```
implementation "androidx.media:media:1.1.0"
```